# how do I concatenate the contents of filelist

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I have an interactive file sorting script that outputs a series of `filelist` for every directory it creates for the sorted output.

How do I concatenate the contents of all `filelist` to one summary file on my desktop.

My code works great, except for this specific task.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Good Morning, Please enter your file type name for sorting [ENTER]:" all_extensions
if cd /Users/christopherdorman/desktop
  then  while read extension
      do    destination="folder$extension"
        mkdir -p "$destination"
        mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
      done   <<< "${all_extensions// /$'\n'}"
        mkdir -p foldermisc 
        if mv  -v unsorted/* "foldermisc"
      then  echo "Good News, the rest of Your files have been successfully processed"
        fi
    for i in folder*/; do
        ls -S "$i" > "${i}filelist” 
        cat > "${i}filelist” | tee ~/desktop/summary.txt
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modification truncates the `summary.txt` file and then does a `cat` of each file into said summary file.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Good Morning, Please enter your file type name for sorting [ENTER]:" all_extensions
if cd /Users/christopherdorman/desktop
  then  while read extension
      do    destination="folder$extension"
        mkdir -p "$destination"
        mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
      done   <<< "${all_extensions// /$'\n'}"
        mkdir -p foldermisc 
        if mv  -v unsorted/* "foldermisc"
      then  echo "Good News, the rest of Your files have been successfully processed"
        fi
    truncate --size 0 ~/desktop/summary.txt
    for i in folder*/; do
        ls -S "$i" > "${i}filelist" 
        cat "${i}filelist" >> ~/desktop/summary.txt
    done
fi
```

Comment: Tried to run the code. this does not output the filelist nor does it produce any output on the desktop,

Comment: What output are you expecting to see in your `summary.txt` file?

Comment: If I have 4 filelist. one in each of the 4 folders on my desktop, the summary.txt  is a collation of the content of those 4 files. i want the content concatenated to one file

Comment: I'm not sure if you directly copied/pasted it, but I had a bad `"` character in there somehow.  Did you see any errors when you ran it?

Comment: I will try and run yours again now, give me a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

There is an odd `”` character (not a `"`, similar but not the same) in both this lines:

```
    ls -S "$i" > "${i}filelist” 
    cat > "${i}filelist” | tee ~/desktop/summary.txt
```

Change both to this ones (copy and paste):

```
    ls -S "$i" > "${i}filelist"
    cat "${i}filelist" | tee -a "summary.txt"
```

Removing the `>` will avoid erasing `"${i}filelist”`.
Adding a `-a` will make tee to `append` to an existing file.

Or, if you want, just use this line:

```
    ls -S "$i" | tee -a "${i}filelist" "summary.txt"
```

The whole script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
mydesktop=/Users/christopherdorman/desktop
read -p "Good Morning, Please enter your file type name for sorting [ENTER]:" all_extensions
if cd "$mydesktop"
then
    while  read extension
    do     destination="folder$extension"
           mkdir -p "$destination"
           mv -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
    done   <<< "${all_extensions// /$'\n'}"

    mkdir  -p foldermisc 

    if     mv  -v unsorted/* "foldermisc"
    then   echo "Good News, the rest of Your files have been successfully processed"
    fi

    for    i in folder*/
    do     ls -S "$i" | tee -a "${i}filelist" "summary.txt"
    done
fi
```

Comment: will try this now and revert back in few minutes, thank you

Comment: afraid not, I get a blank summary.txt and the filelist do not appear in the folders.

Comment: do i need to truncate

Comment: @SyntaxKiller There were bad characters in the script, corrected now. Please try it.